# XmlElement in C#

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have a simple class in C# that I have setup to serialize to XML by using the XmlSerializer class.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("dc", Namespace= dc.NS_DC)]
public class DCItem {

    // books??

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

DCItem serializes great as the code is setup right now (as seen above); however, I would like to change the property "Title" so that it is contained within a "Books" node. For example:

```
<dc>
  <books>
    <title>Joe's Place</title>
  </books>
</dc>
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: You don't need the `Serializable` attribute for XML Serialization!

Comment: I'm confused.. are you simply asking for a `List<Book>` where `Book` has a `Title` property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a Books class:

```
public class Books
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[XmlRoot("dc", Namespace= dc.NS_DC)]
public class DCItem 
{
    [XmlElement("books")]
    public Books Books { get; set; }
}
```

Also notice that I have gotten rid of the Serializable attribute which is used by binary serializers and completely ignored by the XmlSerializer class.

Now since I suspect that you could have multiple books:

```
<dc>
  <books>
    <title>Joe's Place</title>
    <title>second book</title>
    <title>third book</title>
  </books>
</dc>
```

you could adapt your object model to match this structure:

```
[XmlRoot("dc", Namespace= dc.NS_DC)]
public class DCItem
{
    [XmlElement("books")]
    public Books Books { get; set; }
}

public class Books
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public Book[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was kind of the direction I was thinking, but I was more curious if I could just be lazy and not have to through the effort of creating more classes.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you want several `<title>` under `<books>`. Then this is one way of doing it:

```
[XmlType("title")]
public class Title 
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("dc")]
public class DCItem 
{
    [XmlArray("books")]
    public List<Title> Books { get; set; }
}
```

You may want to have a `<book>` element instead though and put title as an attribute or element on `<book>`.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to make a books class that contains a title property.

```
public class booksType
{
    public string title {get;set;}
}
```

And the use that as a type for a books property in the main class.

```
public booksType books {get;set;}
```

Comment: Not a `struct`. Just use a `class`.